# How to save and restore chapter's heading format

Tags: sectioning, formatting, chapters, report

I am writing my thesis using a template provided by the university. It requires using the report class. To format the headings in the front matter, it uses the `titlesec` package and redefine the format (`\titleformat`, `\titlespacing`). However, this also changes the format of chapter headings in the main matter, which I don't like. I have tried using `\newenvironment` to define an environment `preliminary` to wrap the front matter and to only redefine the headings' format locally. However it did not work.

My questions are: is it possible to change the headings' format locally? if not, how to save the default format and restore it after the front matter?

I guess I can always redefine the format after the front matter, but I want to keep the default.

Comment: Please add a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Possibly with a link to your universities template. Also sometimes definitions can be restricted by putting them inside of `{}` or `\begingroup \endgroup`, but I'm not sure if that can work for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `titlesec`'s commands anywhere and their effect will be limited to the group, or environment, containing them.  The following document works with changing of sections and chapters.  For illustration, I have only demonstrated sections; uncomment the lines in the body with `\chapter` commands to see these working too.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\itshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}

\newenvironment{alttitles}{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\normalfont\huge\itshape}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}%
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}}{}

\begin{document}

%\chapter{First chapter}
\section{A section}

\begin{alttitles}
%\chapter{Next chapter}
\section{Another section}

\end{alttitles}

\section{A last section}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

When trying to implement this with your own styles, I suggest you first get the titlesec commands working globally in a spearate document to help debugging.  After that you can build them in to an environment, if you so wish, or simply include them in the appropriate group, e.g.

```
{
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\Large\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}{}
\section{A small caps section}

Text.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change them locally. However, you can revert to the "original" ones at any place in the document, and namely inside the command `\mainmatter`, as shown below. The correct way to define the original titles is described in `titlesec` manual. At this to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\mainmatter}{
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
  \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
  \titleformat{\subsection}
    {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
  \titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
  \titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
  \titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
  \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}
  \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
  \titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
  \titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
  \titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
  \titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}
}
\makeatother
```