# How to revert changes made with titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to save and restore chapter's heading format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69025/how-to-save-and-restore-chapters-heading-format)

I have a document with a structure :

> - Content
> - Appendix
> - Bibliography

As I wanted to change the appearance of appendix-sections in the TOC (so that they would be at the same level in the TOC as the subsections of the **Content** block), I changed the section behaviour with the `titletoc` package (using the command `\titlecontents`).

Now, the question is: how can I revert this so that the **Bibliography** would appear as a normal section in the TOC? I know that I could use `\titlecontents` again, however, if there was a more elegant solution to revert the changes made by `titletoc` to the original values, that would be superb.

Comment: Please, add what you have so far.

Comment: See this similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69025/how-to-save-and-restore-chapters-heading-format